# How do you fight against the entropy in the returned xml from google maps geocoding?

Tags: php

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=55124&sensor=false

For example ^ the url above will take the supplied zip code and return approximate lat and lng coordinates and a formatted address along with "address components" containing things like city,state,country and what not.

The question is (if you play with it and enter different types of addresses) how could you write code that would discern the differences in the address components? how could i be sure that the value i'm seeking is in fact the city and not the street?

It doesn't to be reliable xml. There is entropy if i'm not mistaken. Anyone know a way to guarantee a value?

Answer (score 1):

Each address component has a type like

```
<type>postal_code</type>
```

You can then look for the type you're interested in.

Comment: yes but for more than one address component is the type 'political' (city) from what i've observed.(county also)

Comment: If the type is political, there often is a second type field which describes it more.